# Expose urls for Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm just getting started with docker and docker-compose and I've got into some troubles understanding how to expose services.

I'm going through [this](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/beginner/chapters/votingapp.md) tutorial and it seems to me that they use port exposing to dispatch requests to services. Here is a part of docker-compose.yaml file

```
vote:
  image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote:before
  ports:
    - 5000:80
result:
  image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_result:before
  ports:
    - 5001:80
```

So, they access vote and result services via `localhost:5000` `localhost:5001` respectively. And I'm wondering, is it possible to map these services to urls, so I can access them like `localhost/vote` and `localhost/result`?

Comment: you're trying to access your services on port 80 but you haven't exposed any docker container to listen on port 80. if you had a third container exposed on port 80, maybe something like nginx that can do reverse proxying, that third service could probably help you implement what you're suggesting.

Comment: Not without implementing some kind of gateway in front (apache / nginx etc..)

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's what I was looking for